# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Oracle Linked Server

Tags: sql, database, oracle, linked-server, relational

I am trying to figure out why I am unable to view any of the tables under Query Designer. I am trying to draw data from Oracle as my linked server.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you share the entire image of the Menagment Studio ?

Comment: Can you post your linked server definition?